# iterate over json object duplicates in handlebars

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, handlebars.js

I have the following JSON Object in my javascript:

```
var source = $("#template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

var igListOrig = [
  {
    "IG":"Problem Solving", 
    "AIR_Indicators": "All Domain 1 Indicators* 3.1, 3.2, 3.3,     3.4", 
    "SMP": "SMP 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, and 8", 
    "Purpose": "Students must be able to reason, problem solve, communicate and make real life       decisions that require mathematical thinking.  Teaching students problem solving skills and giving them opportunities to apply their skills is critical to developing their capacity to solve mathematical problems that arise in all our lives (e.g. starting a small business, figuring out the area of a room in order to purchase the correct amount of paint, filling out a tax return, tracking and setting goals for investments, etc.)", 
    "IP":"Problem of the Week(PoW)", 
    "What": "PoWs are complex problems.",
    "When": "PoWs should be administered once per month.", 
    "How": "1.Introduce problem, process, and rubric. 2.Students are given time in class to work on problem throughout the week. 3.Students complete write up. 4.Student peer edit write up. 5.Students revise write up"
  },

  {
    "IG":"Problem Solving", 
    "AIR_Indicators": "All Domain 1 Indicators* 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4",   
    "SMP": "SMP 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, and 8",
    "Purpose": "Students must be able to reason, problem solve, communicate and make real life       decisions that require mathematical thinking.  Teaching students problem solving skills and giving them opportunities to apply their skills is critical to developing their capacity to solve mathematical problems that arise in all our lives (e.g. starting a small business, figuring out the area of a room in order to purchase the correct amount of paint, filling out a tax return, tracking and setting goals for investments, etc.)",
    "IP":"Problem of the Month (POM)", 
    "What": "The POMs are divided into five levels. Students are asked to explain their solutions and reasoning in a write up.",
    "When": "Students should work on problem the first 10-15 minutes of a period for 5-7 consecutive days. ",
    "How": "Write them on a pieces of paper." 
  },

  {
    "IG":"Problem Solving", 
    "AIR_Indicators": "All Domain 1 Indicators* 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4",
    "SMP": "SMP 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, and 8", 
    "Purpose": "Students must be able to reason, problem solve, communicate and make real life       decisions that require mathematical thinking.  Teaching students problem solving skills and giving them opportunities to apply their skills is critical to developing their capacity to solve mathematical problems that arise in all our lives (e.g. starting a small business, figuring out the area of a room in order to purchase the correct amount of paint, filling out a tax return, tracking and setting goals for investments, etc.)", 
    "IP":"Formative Assessment Lesson (FAL)", 
    "What": "FALs consist of 3 parts including a pre-assessment (approximately 15 min.",
    "When": "The 3 part cycle is intended to be given approximately two-thirds the way into a unit of study.", 
    "How": "1.Pre assessment. 2.Introduce activity. 3.Students work collaboratively. 4.Whole class discussion/ presentation. 5.Post assessment." 
  },

 {
    "IG":"Problem Solving", "AIR_Indicators": "All Domain 1 Indicators* 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4",
    "SMP": "SMP 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, and 8", 
    "Purpose": "Students must be able to reason, problem solve, communicate and make real life       decisions that require mathematical thinking.  Teaching students problem solving skills and giving them opportunities to apply their skills is critical to developing their capacity to solve mathematical problems that arise in all our lives (e.g. starting a small business, figuring out the area of a room in order to purchase the correct amount of paint, filling out a tax return, tracking and setting goals for investments, etc.)",   
    "IP":"Mathematics Assessment Resources (MARS)", 
    "What": "Story Problems.",
    "When": "Done at the begining of the unit.", 
    "How": "After each asssessment." }

]

$('body').append(template(igListOrig));
```

And I want to iterate over this object so only when it iterates over the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th object I get a different "IP", "What", "When", and "How" each time AND ignore all the duplicities.  After each of the iterations only the "IP", "What", "When", and "How" are different.  I need to keep these differences and ignore other other duplicates.

I referenced something like this but I think this person's situation was a little different.
[Iterating over a JSON-Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18385307/iterating-over-a-json-object)

Eventually this will go in a handlebars template like this

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<div class="container">
 {{#each this }}
    <div class='titles'>
      <div class="left">Aspire Logo</div>
      <div class="middle">{{IG}}</div>
      <div class="right">Common Core</div>
      <div class="purple"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="split">
      <div class="text">
        <p class="split-heading">
          Aligned to the following <span class="bold">AIR</span> Indicators:
        </p>
        <ul>
          <li>{{AIR_Indicators}}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <p class="split-heading">
          Aligned to the following <span class="bold">Standards of Mathematical Practice:</span>
        </p>
        <ul>
          <li>{{SMP}}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="purpose heading">
        <h3>Purpose</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="purpose text">
        <p>
          {{Purpose}}
        </p>
      </div>
    <div class="process heading">
      <h3> Process </h3>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom-container text">
        <div class="cube">
          <h4>Instructional Practice</h4>
          <center><h3> {{IP}} </h3> </center> </br>
          <p><span class="description">What</span> {{What}} </p></br>
          <p><span class="description">When</span> {{When}} </p></br>
          <p><span class="description">How</span> {{How}} </p></br>
        </div>
    </div>
{{/each}}
</div>
</script>
```

Eventually, the "IP", "What", "When", and "How" will look something like this near the bottom half of the document under the heading "Process"
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ivqr.jpg

Here is the JS Fiddle I'm working with:
http://jsfiddle.net/rr9Vz/

**UPDATE**

I just tried something like this

```
  var ips = [];
   for(var i in igListOrig) {
            var ip = igListOrig[i].IP + igListOrig[i].What + igListOrig[i].When +                     
            igListOrig[i].How ;
            if($.inArray(ip,ips)== -1 ){
                ips.push(ip);
            }
        }
```

And I get the array that I need, but now how do I pass my templating AND this iteration through in handlebars?

**UPDATE 2**

For all intents and purposes the `<div class='bottom-container text>` needs to look like this when Handlebars compiles.

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
   <div class="container">
    <div class='titles'>
      <div class="left">Aspire Logo</div>
      <div class="middle">{{IG}}</div>
      <div class="right">Common Core</div>
      <div class="purple"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="split">
      <div class="text">
        <p class="split-heading">
          Aligned to the following <span class="bold">AIR</span> Indicators:
        </p>
        <ul>
          <li>{{AIR_Indicators}}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <p class="split-heading">
          Aligned to the following <span class="bold">Standards of Mathematical Practice:</span>
        </p>
        <ul>
          <li>{{SMP}}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="purpose heading">
        <h3>Purpose</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="purpose text">
        <p>
          {{Purpose}}
        </p>
      </div>
    <div class="process heading">
      <h3> Process </h3>
    </div>  
  <div class="bottom-container text">
    <div class="cube">
      <h4>Instructional Practice</h4>
      <center><h3> Problem Solving</h3> </center> </br>
      <p><span class="description">What</span> PoWs are complex problems. </p></br>
      <p><span class="description">When</span> PoWs should be administered once per month. </p></br>
      <p><span class="description">How</span> 1.Introduce problem, process, and rubric. 2.Students are given time in class to work on problem throughout the week. 3.Students complete write up. 4.Student peer edit write up. 5.Students revise write up</p></br>
    </div>
    <div class="cube">
      <h4>Instructional Practice</h4>
      <center><h3> Problem of the Month (POM) </h3> </center> </br>
      <p><span class="description">What</span> The POMs are divided into five levels. Students are asked to explain their solutions and reasoning in a write up. </p></br>
      <p><span class="description">When</span> Students should work on problem the first 10-15 minutes of a period for 5-7 consecutive days. </p></br>
      <p><span class="description">How</span> Write them on a pieces of paper. </p></br>
    </div>
    <div class="cube">
      <h4>Instructional Practice</h4>
      <center><h3> Formative Assessment Lesson (FAL) </h3> </center> </br>
      <p><span class="description">What</span> FALs consist of 3 parts including a pre-assessment (approximately 15 min. </p></br>
      <p><span class="description">When</span> The 3 part cycle is intended to be given approximately two-thirds the way into a unit of study. </p></br>
      <p><span class="description">How</span> 1.Pre assessment. 2.Introduce activity. 3.Students work collaboratively. 4.Whole class discussion/ presentation. 5.Post assessment. </p></br>
    </div>
    <div class="cube">
      <h4>Instructional Practice</h4>
      <center><h3> Mathematics Assessment Resources (MARS)</h3> </center> </br>
      <p><span class="description">What</span> Story Problems. </p></br>
      <p><span class="description">When</span> Done at the begining of the unit. </p></br>
      <p><span class="description">How</span> After each asssessment. </p></br>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I want this: http://jsfiddle.net/8Xnpk/1/

but I'm getting this:  http://jsfiddle.net/rr9Vz/3/

@MarcoCl's solution works in terms of code execution, but for whatever eason I can't seem to get this http://jsfiddle.net/8Xnpk/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to avoid duplicates, use a dictionary instead of an array: this speed up the duplicate lookup and it won't hurt your current code.

```
function filterDuplicates(array){
  // this will hold the new filtered dictionary
  var uniqArray  = [],
  // this is used for the lookup
      dupCheck = {};
  for( var i=0; i< array.length; i++){
    var entry = array[i];
    var uniqueKey = entry.IP + entry.What + entry.When + entry.How;
    if(!dupCheck[uniqueKey]){
      // here there are only unique values
      dupCheck[uniqueKey] = true;
      uniqArray.push(entry);
    }
  }
  return uniqArray;
}

var source = $("#template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var igListOrig = [...];

$('body').append(template(filterDuplicates(igListOrig)));
```

As alternative you can integrate the `filterDuplicates` logic in a custom Handlebar helper.

Replace the `{{#each this}}` tag with the custom `{{€#eachUnique this}}` one:

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div class="container">
    {{#eachUnique this}}
    ...
    {{/eachUnique}}
  </div>
</script>
```

Then register the new helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('eachUnique', function(array, options) {
  // this is used for the lookup
  var  dupCheck = {};
  // template buffer
  var buffer = '';
  for( var i=0; i< array.length; i++){
    var entry = array[i];
    var uniqueKey = entry.IP + entry.What + entry.When + entry.How;
    // check if the entry has been added already
    if(!dupCheck[uniqueKey]){
      // here there are only unique values
      dupCheck[uniqueKey] = true;
      // add this in the template
      buffer += options.fn(entry);
    }
  }
  // return the template compiled
  return buffer;
});
```

### Update 2

The problem changed a bit from the original one - it was only about removing duplicates from a list and it became a more template-related question...

I'll leave the duplicate answer and add this other one for the second update:

Preprocess your data to remove the common data:

```
var source = $("#template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var igListOrig = [...];

var newModel = {
  'IG': igListOrig[0].IG,
  'AIR_Indicators': igListOrig[0].AIR_Indicators,
  'SMP': igListOrig[0].SMP, 
  'Purpose':igListOrig[0].Purpose ,
  entries: igListOrig
};
$('body').append(template(newModel));
```

The new template will look like this one:

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div class="container">
    <div class='titles'>
    <div class="left">Aspire Logo</div>
    <div class="middle">{{IG}}</div>
  <div class="right">Common Core</div>
  <div class="purple"></div>
</div>
<div class="split">
  <div class="text">
    <p class="split-heading">
      Aligned to the following <span class="bold">AIR</span> Indicators:
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li>{{AIR_Indicators}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p class="split-heading">
      Aligned to the following <span class="bold">Standards of Mathematical Practice:</span>
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li>{{SMP}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="purpose heading">
    <h3>Purpose</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="purpose text">
    <p>
      {{Purpose}}
    </p>
  </div>
<div class="process heading">
  <h3> Process </h3>
</div>  
<div class="bottom-container text">
// use eachUnique here instead of each to avoid duplicates
  {{eachUnique items}}
    <div class="cube">
      <h4>Instructional Practice</h4>
      <center><h3>{{IP}}</h3> </center> </br>
      <p><span class="description">What</span> {{What}} </p></br>
      <p><span class="description">When</span> {{When}}</p></br>
      <p><span class="description">How</span> {{How}}</p></br>
    </div>
  {{/eachUnique}}
 </div>
</div>
</script>
```

Comment: @MarcoCl, thanks for the reply.  I tried your first solution but I am still left with duplicate forms.  I'm trying to get "IP", "What", "When", and "How" all in one form in `<div class="bottom-container text">.  Here's the JS Fiddle with  your code http://jsfiddle.net/rr9Vz/3/  In your second solution, I tried reading the docs regarding helpers, I'm still a bit confused on where I add the 'eachUnique' in the template.  Thanks for helping out.

Comment: Any other thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: You are using 4 "fields" to find duplicates: "IP" + "What" + "When" + "How". From a quick look the "What" field is different an all the entries: the key will consequentially be different for each entry, that's why it doesn't filter.

Comment: Sorry to bother again, I used the filter helper again and it gives me and error: TypeError: object is not a function, at line `buffer += fn(entry).  Hopefully you can take a look again. So I clarified the question..You are absolutely right the keys will be different, for "IP", "What", "When" and "How" and that's the expected return I need.  But I can't get them displaying in the divs side by side without repeating the keys, thanks and I hope you'll take a look at it again.

Comment: It is right: `fn` is a property of the second argument, not a function itself. Updated the code.

Comment: Hey @MarcoCI thanks for the help again.  I ran the code again and it's correct, however the outcome is not what I'm expecting.  I updated the question again where it says "UPDATED 2." Hopefully it'll clarify things.  I feel we're almost there!  Very appreciative of your help so far.  :)

Comment: @gary1410 the first 4 fields `"IG", "AIR_Indicators", "SMP", "Purpose"` are always the same. I would recommend to change the model to match that and change consequently the template. I'll update the code above.